# How to write asynchronous functions for Node.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node.js

I've tried to research on how exactly asynchronous functions should be written. After a lot of plowing through a lot of documentation, it's still unclear to me.

**How do I write asynchronous functions for Node? How should I implement error event handling correctly?**

Another way to ask my question would be this: How should I interpret the following function?

```
var async_function = function(val, callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback(val);
    });
};
```

Also, I found **[this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878008/how-do-i-create-a-non-blocking-asynchronous-function-in-node-js)** ("How do I create a non-blocking asynchronous function in node.js?") interesting. I don't feel like it has been answered yet.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. It's not apparent to me how these functions are any different.

Comment: I recommend you look at `setTimeout` and `setInterval` in your favourite browser and play around with them as well. Or ajax callbacks (probably the closest thing to the node experience), or event listeners for things you're familiar with like click and load events. The asynchronous model exists already in the browser, and they're exactly the same in node.

Comment: @davin - Guess I don't fully comprehend the asynchronous model then.

Comment: @Kriem, I answered something yesterday that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883648/how-to-send-a-return-form-a-callback-function-to-the-main-function/ It's not an answer to your question, but it's on-topic. Try and read the question and answer there and play around with the code to try and understand what is going on.

Comment: @davin - Thanks! Interesting read. The asynchronicity with its callback functions really has me baffled.

Comment: @Raynos What is the definition of "asynchronous function"?

Comment: I thought that anything that uses a socket (database, streams..) causes the function to be asynch, but I may be excluding other cases where the function behaves asynch'ly too

Comment: https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Comment: I see a lot of examples using setTimeout or setInterval, but I don't understand why they are used.  Are they used to simulate something, as to provide some academic exercise to understand how asynchronous transactions work with no real or clear business use case, or are they fundamentally required for any asynchronous function regardless of business use case and/or requirements?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You seem to be confusing asynchronous IO with asynchronous functions. node.js uses asynchronous non-blocking IO because non blocking IO is better. The best way to understand it is to go watch some videos by ryan dahl.

> **How do I write asynchronous functions for Node?**

Just write normal functions, the only difference is that they are not executed immediately but passed around as callbacks.

> **How should I implement error event handling correctly**

Generally API's give you a callback with an err as the first argument. For example

```
database.query('something', function(err, result) {
  if (err) handle(err);
  doSomething(result);
});
```

Is a common pattern.

Another common pattern is `on('error')`. For example

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

**Edit:**

```
var async_function = function(val, callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback(val);
    });
};
```

The above function when called as

```
async_function(42, function(val) {
  console.log(val)
});
console.log(43);
```

Will print `42` to the console asynchronously. In particular `process.nextTick` fires after the current eventloop callstack is empty. That call stack is empty after `async_function` and `console.log(43)` have run. So we print 43 followed by 42.

You should probably do some reading on the event loop.

Comment: I've seen the Dahl vids, but I don't seem to get a grasp on the matter I'm afraid. :(

Comment: @Kriem see updated answer and read [about the event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)

Comment: Thanks fort the insights. I'm now more aware of what I lack in knowledge. :) Your last example helped by the way.

Comment: I think you're statement about asynchronous IO is "better" is too general. In this sense yes, but overall that may not be the case.

Comment: In your first code example, you check the err argument, but didn't return afterward.  In the case of an error, the code will continue and potentially cause serious problems in your application.

Answer (score 9):

Just passing by callbacks is not enough.
You have to use settimer for example, to make function async.

Examples:
Not async functions:

```
function a() {
  var a = 0;    
  for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
    a++;
  };
  b();
};

function b() {
  var a = 0;    
  for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
    a++;
  };    
  c();
};

function c() {
  for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
  };
  console.log("async finished!");
};

a();
console.log("This should be good");
```

If you will run above example, This should be good, will have to wait untill those functions will finish to work.

Pseudo multithread (async) functions:

```
function a() {
  setTimeout ( function() {
    var a = 0;  
    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
      a++;
    };
    b();
  }, 0);
};

function b() {
  setTimeout ( function() {
    var a = 0;  
    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
      a++;
    };  
    c();
  }, 0);
};

function c() {
  setTimeout ( function() {
    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
    };
    console.log("async finished!");
  }, 0);
};

a();
console.log("This should be good");
```

This one will be trully async.
This should be good will be writen before async finished.

Answer (score 5):

You should watch this: [Node Tuts episode 19 - Asynchronous Iteration Patterns](https://vimeo.com/19519289)

It should answers your questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you KNOW that a function returns a promise, i suggest using the new async/await features in JavaScript. It makes the syntax look synchronous but work asynchronously. When you add the `async` keyword to a function, it allows you to `await` promises in that scope:

```
async function ace() {
  var r = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true)
  });

  console.log(r); // true
}
```

if a function does not return a promise, i recommend wrapping it in a new promise that you define, then resolve the data that you want:

```
function ajax_call(url, method) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, { method })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => { resolve(json); })
  });
}

async function your_function() {
  var json = await ajax_call('www.api-example.com/some_data', 'GET');
  console.log(json); // { status: 200, data: ... }
}
```

Bottom line: leverage the power of Promises.

Comment: Thing to remember here is, body of promise is still executed synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for both node and the browser.

```
isNode = (typeof exports !== 'undefined') &&
(typeof module !== 'undefined') &&
(typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') &&
(typeof navigator === 'undefined' || typeof navigator.appName === 'undefined') ? true : false,
asyncIt = (isNode ? function (func) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    func();
  });
} : function (func) {
  setTimeout(func, 5);
});
```

Comment: 4 downvotes and not even one constructive comment.. :\

Comment: @Omer Such is life on SO.

Comment: @NorbertoBezi Maybe the code is self explanatory to you, but not to the one who posted the answer. That's why it's always a good practice to explain upon downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealing too many hours for such task in for node.js. I'm mainly front-end guy.

I find this quite important, because all node methods asyncronous deal with callback, and transform it into Promise is better to handle it.

I Just want to show a possible outcome, more lean and readable. Using ECMA-6 with async you can write it like this.

```
 async function getNameFiles (dirname) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dirname, (err, filenames) => {
      err !== (undefined || null) ? reject(err) : resolve(filenames)
    })
  })
}
```

the `(undefined || null)` is for **repl** (read event print loop) scenarios,
using undefined also work.