# Determine whether a method is synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, is it possible to determine (using a function) whether a method is synchronous or asynchronous?

I'd like to write a function that does the following:

```
function isSynchonous(methodName) {
    //if the method is synchronous, return true. Otherwise, return false.
}
```

Comment: A relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898779/how-to-write-asynchronous-functions-for-node-js

Answer (score 8):

From a language standpoint this is not possible, which I believe llambda's answer proves.

- Functions can do things asynchronously but return something synchronously; say, return the number of async tasks that were fired off.
- Functions can synchronously return promises...  that represent asynchronous information. I would call such a method asynchronous but the language can't really tell that.
- In some perverse sense every asynchronous function "returns" something... `undefined` if nothing else.

From an engineering standpoint:

- read the documentation.
- If the function accepts a callback, it is likely asynchronous. Look at the function signature.
- Read the code.
- Use "common sense." If the function does IO and returns a result from IO it must be, in some case, asynchronous. This includes file reading, reading from standard input, saving to a database, and HTTP/AJAX requests. Note streams are often used for this, which represents an asynchronous task, but the callbacks are special.

Furthermore there *are* functions that mix the two.

```
function(callback) {
    if(ready) {
        callback();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(callback, 5000);
    }
}
```

Arguably this is very evil, and correct practice would be

```
if(ready) {
    process.nextTick(callback);
}
```

so the function has uniform behavior.

**However there *is* a hacky way to tell if anything asynchronous happened, at least in Node.js**. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960452/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-callbacks-in-the-node-work-queue-or-why-wont-node-ex).

```
// untested!! please read the documentation on these functions before using yourself
var work = process._getActiveHandles().length + process._getActiveCallbacks().length;
foo;
var newWork = (process._getActiveHandles().length + process._getActiveCallbacks().length) - work;
if(newWork > 0) {
    console.log("asynchronous work took place.");
}
```

This works because asynchronous work cannot resolve on the same tick, by definition, and because Node.js is single threaded.

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily know. A function could even be randomly synchronous or asynchronous.

For example, a function that takes another function could execute that function immediately, or it could schedule to execute it at a later time using setImmediate or nextTick. The function could even randomly choose to call its passed function synchronously or asynchronous, such as:

```
console.log('Start')

function maybeSynchOrAsync(fun) {

  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2))

  if (rand == 0) {
    console.log('Executing passed function synchronously')
    fun()
    console.log('Done.')
  } else {
    console.log('Executing passed function asynchronously via setImmediate')
    setImmediate(fun)
    console.log('Done.')
  }
}

maybeSynchOrAsync(function () { console.log('The passed function has executed.') });
```

Further, technically speaking, every function call is synchronous. If you call a function *F*, and *F* queues a callback function to be invoked later (using setTimeout or whatever mechanism), the original function *F* still has a synchronous return value (whether it's undefined, a promise, a thunk, or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

No, that's impossible. The methods aren't just marked synchronous or asynchronous, they either use callbacks or they don't.

Comment: I don't understand why it's impossible. I could try inspecting a method's source code; would that give any indication of whether or not the method was synchronous?

Comment: Also, is there a clear distinction between "synchronous functions" and "asynchronous functions" in Javascript, or is it possible for a function to be either synchronous and asynchronous in different use cases?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Inspecting a method's source code to determine if it's asynchronous is unfortunately equivalent to solving the halting problem, and isn't meaningful anyway. No, there isn't a clear distinction between synchronous functions and asynchronous functions. The difference is that they may take a callback and call it asynchronously. They may also call it synchronously. There's a mixture of the two - a synchronous operation that calls an asynchronous one. Some functions automatically decide based on the presence of a callback. Asynchronicity isn't a language feature.

Comment: note it's argued mixed sync/async is evil. If it's sync it should still happen on `process.nextTick`

Comment: @djechlin: That applies for I/O; how about computing a factorial? It depends.

Comment: What do you mean? A factorial should sometime return sync and sometimes async?

Comment: @djechlin: Well, a factorial can take a long time to compute with the right input; does that mean mixing it with code that uses a callback is bad?

Comment: I still don't understand your example, you can of course call a computationally expensive function from a callback or anywhere, to the same extent that you should be doing that in node in the first place.

Comment: @djechlin: well, my answer (and the longer comment) is about how there’s no clear line between “synchronous” and “asynchronous” code. Even more than that, I don’t think there should be (and promises are a good way of accomplishing that).

Comment: Maybe you're saying blocking calls e.g. for CPU intensive tasks are synchronous from the process's standpoint, but may "feel" asynchronous in wall time? but overall yes

Answer (score 2):

Why exactly do you need to know, is the real question.

Having said that; that's possible with the new JS abstractions. Nowadays for the async functions those explicitly defined by a preceding `async` keyword you can perform a test like;

```
async function test(){}
var type = Object.getPrototypeOf(test).constructor.name;
console.log(type); // <- 'AsyncFunction'
```

cool..!

As for the normal functions those happen to return a promise, we must remember that it's just a sync function returning a promise object right away, synchronously. That means you have to check dynamically if a function returns a promise in advance, before invoking the function. I think that takes you to a type level programming adventure which exists in sophisticated languages like Haskell etc.

Comment: I posted this question several years ago (in 2012), when this feature of JavaScript did not yet exist.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes sure :) I just think your question is a good one and still valid so placed an answer for the sake completeness.