# How to check whether a function in Node.js runs synchronously or asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, sails.js, event-loop

Is there a way to know this through memory analysis or some way of application profiling?

Comment: Here is a detailed answer to a very similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680270/determine-whether-a-method-is-synchronous-or-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

There is no sure way to check programmatically. Either check the documentation or source code to be absolutely sure if the function name does not have the traditional `Sync` suffix.