# How can I make node wait? or perhaps a different solution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using https://github.com/gpittarelli/node-ssq to query of a bunch of TF2 game servers to find out if they are on, and if so, how many players are inside.
Once I find a server that is on and has less than 6 players in it, I want to use that server's Database ID to insert into somewhere else.

Code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0;i < servers.length;i++) {

                ssq.info(""+servers[i].ip, servers[i].port, function (err, data) {

                    serverData = deepCopy(data);
                    serverError = deepCopy(err);
                });

                if (!serverError) {

                    if (serverData.numplayers < 6){
                        //its ok
                        currentServer = servers[i].id;
                        i = 99999;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (i == servers.length-1){
                        currentServer = 666;
                    }
                }

            }
```

And then right after I insert into database with https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql .
If I put a console.log(serverData) in there, the info will show up in the console AFTER it inserted into the DB and did a couple other stuff.

So how do I "stop" node, or should I be looking at this / doing this differently?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

A simple solution here is to just move your `if` statements inside the callback function:

```
for (var i = 0;i < servers.length;i++) {
  ssq.info(""+servers[i].ip, servers[i].port, function (err, data) {

      serverData = deepCopy(data);
      serverError = deepCopy(err);

      // moving inside the function, so we have access to defined serverData and serverError
      if (!serverError) {

          if (serverData.numplayers < 6){
              //its ok
              currentServer = servers[i].id;
              i = 99999;
              /* add an additional function here, if necessary */
          }
      }
      else {
          if (i == servers.length-1){
              currentServer = 666;
              /* add an additional function here, if necessary */
          }
      }
  });
  // serverData and serverError are undefined outside of the function
  // because node executes these lines without waiting to see if ``ssq.info`` 
  // has finished. 
}
```

Any additional functions within the callback to `ssq.info` will have access to variables defined within that function. Do be careful with nesting too many anonymous functions.

**Original (nodesque) Answer**
If `ssq.info` is an Asynchronous function (which it seem it is), Node is going to immediately execute it and move on, only dealing with the callback function (which you passed as a last parameter)  when `ssq.info` has finished. That is why your `console.log` statement is going to execute immediately. This is the beauty/terror of node's asynchronous nature : )

You can use `setTimeout` to make Node wait, but that will hold up **every** other process on your server.

The better solution, in my opinion, would be to make use of Node's [Event Emiters](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html), to:

1. watch for an event (in this case, when a player leaves a server)
2. Check if the number of players is less than 6
3. If so, execute your query function (using  a callback)

A good primer on this is:  [Mixu's Node Book - Control Flow](http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html). Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898978/1048479) SO post.

Comment: Ok, I think I now better understand what "node never stops" means. The thing is, how do I set up an event for when a player joins or leaves the server? ssq.info basiclly queries the server to find out a bunch of stuff about it, one of which is the numplayers property. I do not have a constant monitor on the server, I just need which server is on and has less than 5 players, so that I can use it and redirect 12 players to it.

Comment: Okay, i've updated my answer with something that should help you, since you are not using an evented system. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback,

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO table', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
     //entry should be inserted here.

});
```

also the http://www.sequelizejs.com/ library is a bit more matrue, it could be an implementation problem with node-mysql