# Node.js how to read a file and then write the same file with two separate functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I want to do is read a file and then be able to perform other operations with that information as I write the file. For example:

read file
write file and at the same time perform MD5 hash, digital signing etc.

I could use fs.readfile and fs.writefile as one operation and just copy the file from the web server to my computer, but I don't think I could still do these same operations. Anyway, skipping the in between stuff. How do I use fs.readfile and writefile to create two separate functions to copy a file? Here is what I have been working on, and yes I've read these forums extensively in search of an answer.

```
var fs = require('fs');



function getData(srcPath) { 
fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return data;
        }
    );
}


function writeData(savPath, srcPath) {
        fs.writeFile (savPath, (getData(srcPath)), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
            console.log('complete');
        }
    );
}
//getData ('./test/test.txt');
writeData ('./test/test1.txt','./test/test.txt');
```

I want to be able to download files of any type and just make raw copies, with md5 hash etc attached to a JSON file.  That will probably be a question for later though.

Comment: getData does nothing in your code. you need to to call writeFile in the callback of readFile. if you want to git-r-dun, there's always fs.readFileSync(), which works as you probably expect it to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As suggested by dandavis in his comment, `readFile` does nothing because it is an asynchronous call. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898779/how-to-write-asynchronous-functions-for-node-js) for additional information on what that means.

In short, an async call will never wait for the result to return. In your example, `getData` does not wait for `readFile()` to return the result you want, but will finish right away. Async calls are usually handled by passing `callbacks`, which is the last parameter to `readFile` and `writeFile`.

In any case, there are two ways to do this:

1.Do it asynchronously (which is the proper way):

```
function copyData(savPath, srcPath) {
    fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //Do your processing, MD5, send a satellite to the moon, etc.
            fs.writeFile (savPath, data, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('complete');
            });
        });
}
```

2.Do it synchronously. Your code won't have to change much, you will just need to replace `readFile` and `writeFile` by `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync` respectively. **Warning**: using this method is not only against best practises, but defies the very purpose of using nodejs (unless of course you have a very legitimate reason).

**Edit**: As per OP's request, here is one possible way to separate the two methods, e.g., using callbacks:

```
function getFileContent(srcPath, callback) { 
    fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(data);
        }
    );
}

function copyFileContent(savPath, srcPath) { 
    getFileContent(srcPath, function(data) {
        fs.writeFile (savPath, data, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('complete');
        });
    });
}
```

This way, you are separating the read part (in `getFileContent`) from the copy part.

Comment: From what your saying, it would be a frivolous waste of time to do this synchronously.  I just thought it would be easier to section off readfile and writeful as seperate functions in case I would ever need to use just one and not the other within the program. Still, if I can do all the processing correctly, this works better. I will just have to try it and see if it works.

Comment: Check out my edit for how to separate the read from the copying. You can apply the same technique to writeFile (e.g. passing a callback).

Comment: I think it's an overstatement to say that doing this synchronously "defies the very purpose of using nodejs".  Yes, it's true that nodejs makes possible, and encourages, a programming style in which any operation that could take a certain amount of time is done asynchronously.  However, in this case the OP's purpose of using nodejs is simply to run a program written in javascript, and using synchronous calls might be a very appropriate style for a program like this.

Comment: @Duncan "unless of course you have a very legitimate reason": simply running a program wirrten in JS is a legitimate reason

Answer (score 5):

I had to use this recently, so I converted verybadallocs answer to promises.

```js
function readFile (srcPath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}

function writeFile (savPath, data) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.writeFile(savPath, data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve()
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Then using them is simple.

```js
readFile('path').then(function (results) {
  results += ' test manipulation'
  return writeFile('path', results)
}).then(function () {
  //done writing file, can do other things
})
```

Usage for async/await

```js
const results = await readFile('path')
results += ' test manipulation'
await writeFile('path', results)
// done writing file, can do other things
```

Answer (score 0):

To read and write a file with Non-blocking or  Asynchronous way, you can use the advance features of es6 or higher like Promise or Async/await, but you must keep eye on **Polyfills** (https://javascript.info/polyfills) or if there are only a couple of read/write you can use call back Hell.

```
function readFiles(){
    fs.readFile('./txt/start.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data1)=>{
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        fs.readFile(`./txt/${data1}.txt`, 'utf-8', (err, data2)=>{
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            fs.readFile('./txt/append.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data3)=>{
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                writeFile('./txt/final.txt', `${data2}\n${data3}`);
            });
        });
    });
}

function writeFile(path, data){
    fs.writeFile(path,data,'utf-8',err=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
readFiles();
```