# Using more than one unirest requests with Sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have the following code

```
index: function (req, res) {

  var Request = unirest.get("https://poker.p.mashape.com/index.php?players=4").headers({ "X-Mashape-Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }).end(function (response) {
    players = response.body;

    showdown_total = players.showdown.length;
    showdown = Array();


  });
  console.log(players);

  // Send a JSON response
  res.view({
    hello: 'world',
    //players: players
  });

},
```

It works great if I add the **res.view** inside unirest **get**, but I want to send those variables to the **view** and be able to add another unirest request

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how [*asynchronous code*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898779/how-to-write-asynchronous-functions-for-node-js) works in Node.js.

Basically, when an operation doesn't evaluate ASAP, node doesn't wait for it. It just says, *"fine, no worries, just tell me when you are done"*.. sort of.

The thing is, in your code, you don't tell node when your *get request*. is done. You just fire away the *view* to the client before the *request function* even starts thinking about fetching the data.

**How to make node wait ?**

You have some options. Either, give it a *callback function* (do this when you are done), or you have to nest your functions. Those two are kind of the same thing really.

I'll show you one solution, *nested functions*:

```
var urlOne = "https://poker.p.mashape.com/index.php?players=4",
    urlTwo = "http://some.other.url",
    headers = { "X-Mashape-Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" };

// Run first request
unirest.get(urlOne).headers(headers).end(function (response) {
    players = response.body;
    showdown_total = players.showdown.length;
    showdown = Array();

    // Run second request
    unirest.get(urlTwo).headers(headers).end(function (response) {
        someVar = response.body;

        // Show all my data to the client
        res.view({
            players: players,
            someOther: someVar
        });
    });
});
```

Other solutions:

- If you don't want to nest the functions, give them a *callback* to run when they are done.
- Use a module for handling asynchronous code, for example [one of the more popular ones](https://github.com/caolan/async) called *Async*.

I would suggest you to read more about callbacks, asynchronous code and nodejs before jumping directly on the external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way....you could use fibers!

Read some docs [here!](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html)

```
var sync = require('synchronize');

index: function (req, res) {
    sync.fiber(function(){

        var response = sync.await(
            unirest.get("https://poker.p.mashape.com/index.php?players=4").headers(
                { "X-Mashape-Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
            ).end(sync.defer())
        );

        var players = response.body;
        console.log(players);

        // Send a JSON response
        res.view({
            hello: 'world',
            players: players
        });
    });
}
```