# Async function doesn't work in global environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise, es6-modules

I created sets of async functions in global environment. I want to re-use the async functions across all the modules. When I call the re-use async function in other module, it returned undefined.

**Global**

```
module.exports = ((global) => {
   return {
     async funcA(){
       return Promise.resolve();
     },
     async funcB(){
       return Promise.resolve();
     }
   }
})
```

**Endpoint**

```
module.exports = ((global) => {
   return async(req, res, next) => {
     var getA = await global.funcA(); // Undefined
   };
});
```

**Routes**

```
import global from './global';

console.log(global); // all the scripts
console.log(global.funcA); // Undefined

let endpoint = require('./endpoint')(global);


api.get('/test', endpoint);
```

Comment: First of all read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898978/3030495) and decide to do you want to create an async function or use async function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should not use the term **global** as Node.js already uses this.

Anyhow, it looks like you are trying to export some functions from a file called **global** which you can then import and use across your application.

---

**GlobalFuncs**

You don’t need to export async functions as you are just returning a promise. You also don’t need a function taking **global** as an argument.

So you can just export an object containing the two functions:

```
module.exports = {
  funcA() {
    return Promise.resolve('Value A')
  },
  funcB() {
    return Promise.resolve('Value B')
  }
}
```

---

**Endpoint**

This is where you want an **async** function as you are using the **await** keyword:

```
const globalFuncs = require('./global-funcs')

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  let getA = await globalFuncs.funcA()

  // Send result as response (amend as necessary)
  res.send(getA)
}
```

---

**Routes**

Here you can just import your **endpoint** function and use it in your routes:

```
const endpoint = require('./endpoint')

api.get('/test', endpoint)
```