# How to start setinterval in server answer?

Tags: setinterval

For example we have code like this :

```
        setInterval(function () { // Content value
        counttime.value = "10000";
    }, 2000);
```

we need it , when server accept our request
we dont want to send this command , before server acception
i need example about that

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `clearInterval`.

Comment: i'd strongly recommend to use an **asynchronous function** instead of an setInterval to wait for the server to respond.

Comment: @tipsfedora do you have any sample ?

Comment: quite difficult to understand as a a beginner, but here it's explained quite good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898779/how-to-write-asynchronous-functions-for-node-js